# AJAX submit form data fails. It works using $_GET when i turn off e.preventdefault

Tags: php, html, ajax, form-data

This is my first post here. Sorry if my English appears to be bad.

I attempted to use the following codes to submit form data to my signup/submit/index.php.

Here is my sample HTML

```
    <form name="signup_form" id="signup_form" action="submit">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CreateUsername" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="CreatePassword" name="password" id="password"></form>
```

Here is my Ajax

```
 .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();


        loadshow();

         var $form = $(e.target),
            fv    = $form.data('formValidation');

        // Use Ajax 
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#signup_form').serialize(), //or $form.serialize()
            success: function(result) {
                // ... Process the result ...
                //alert(result);
                if (result=="2")
                {
                swal({
                  type: "success",  
                  title: "HiHi!",
                  text: "GoodLuck",
                  animation: "slide-from-top",
                  showConfirmButton: true
                  }, function(){   

                    var username = $("#username").val();
                    var password = $("#password").val();
                    functionA(username,password).done(functionB);

                });



                }
                else (result=="agent_na")
                {
                swal({
                  type: "error",    
                  title: "ERROR",
                  text: "N/A",
                  animation: "slide-from-top",
                  showConfirmButton: true
                });
```

Here goes my PhP

```
<?php
  $params = array();
$gett = $_POST["username"];
parse_str($gett,$params);

print_r ($gett); // it prints an empty array
print_r ($gett); // it prints an empty array
echo $params["username"]  // it shows undefined username index
?>
```

I have attempted to serialize $gett before parse_str it. It returns me (){}[].

Could please assist me on this?? I spent almost 20 hours on this, google and tried a lot. Am new to JS.

Comment: Try formData instead of serialize `var formData = new FormData($('#signup_form'));`

Comment: HI. Thanks for your reply!!. I have attempted but still got an empty array in my PHP.. I still got my ALERT. Does it mean AJAX success with no data passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to keep it simple

**HTML**

```
<!-- Include Jquery Plugin -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signup_form">
   <input type="text" name="username"  placeholder="Enter the user name" />
   <input type="password" name="password"    placeholder="Enter password here" />
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<script>
    /* Page loaded */
    $(function(){
        /* Trigger when the form submitted */
        $("#signup_form").submit(function(e) {          
            var form = $(this);         
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "backend.php",
                data: form.serialize(), // Checkout the document - https://api.jquery.com/serialize/
                success: function(data) {
                    // handle the return data from server
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        })
    })
</script>
```

**PHP (backend.php)**

```
<?php
    // Always check param exists before accessing it
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        // Print all the post params
        print_r($_POST);
        // or by param
        // echo "User Name: " . $_POST['username']. " <br />";
        // echo "Password: " . $_POST['username']. " <br />";
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of how you can debug an ajax call:

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#signup_form").submit(function(e) {          
        var formData = new FormData($(this));         
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "backend.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                // if (data.length > 0) ....
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup_form'])){
    $params = array();
    $gett   = $_POST['username'];
    parse_str($gett,$params);

    print_r ($gett);
    echo $_POST['username'];
}else{
    die('No $_POST data.');
}
?>
```

Your php code had some problems in it, you missed a semi-colon and you tried to print from an empty array, calls through ajax won't show any run time errors, and thus you need to be very careful when you're trying to debug an ajax to php call.

Hope this helps.